# Propriedade will-change do CSS: quando utilizar?

Tags: css

De acordo com a [especificação W3C](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-will-change-1/), a propriedade `will-change` tem como objetivo informar ao navegador quais são as propriedades do CSS que serão modificadas para que o mesmo possa fazer otimizações sobre os elementos em questão. Por exemplo, se eu desejar alterar a opacidade de um link, posso fazer o seguinte:

```css
.element { transition: opacity .2s; opacity: 1; }
.element:hover { will-change: opacity; }
.element:active { opacity: .3; }
```

```html
<a href="#" class="element">Stack Overflow em Português</a>
<br>
<sub>Pressione o link acima para ver o efeito em ação</sub>
```

Ou seja, quando o *mouse* estiver sobre o elemento, eu adiciono a propriedade `will-change` definindo a propriedade `opacity`, informando ao navegador que tal propriedade poderá sofrer alterações em breve e então ele pode efetuar otimizações sobre o elemento modificado.

A questão é que a própria especificação descreve o uso desta propriedade como delicada e eu particularmente nunca vi algum lugar utilizando-a, então pergunto:

- Como funciona a propriedade `will-change`?
- Que tipo de otimização o navegador consegue fazer quando a propriedade é utilizada?
- Quando o uso desta propriedade é necessário?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## Considerações Inciais

A propriedade CSS `will-change`, foi criada com a principal intenção de viabilizar os navegadores realizarem otimizações com antecedência, antes do elemento ser efetivamente modificado.

---

## Como funciona a propriedade will-change?

Para utilizar a propriedade CSS `will-change`, devemos informar como seu valor o nome da propriedade que se espera que haja uma animação ou mudança. Os valores podem ser:

```
/* Valores chave */
will-change: auto;
will-change: scroll-position;
will-change: contents;
will-change: transform;        /* Exemplo de <custom-ident> */
will-change: opacity;          /* Exemplo de <custom-ident> */
will-change: left, top;        /* Exemplo de dois <animateable-feature> */

/* Valores globais */
will-change: inherit;
will-change: initial;
will-change: unset;
```

**`auto`**

Essa palavra chave não expressa nenhuma intenção em particular; o user agent deve aplicar qualquer otimização como normalmente ocorre.

O  pode ser um dos seguintes valores:

**`scroll-position`**

Indica que o autor espera que haja uma animação ou mudança na posição do scroll do elemento no futuro.

**`contents`**

Indica que o autor espera que haja uma animação ou mudança no conteúdo do elemento no futuro.

**`<custom-ident>`**

Indica que o autor espera que haja uma animação ou mudança na propriedade com o nome dado no elemento no futuro. Isso não pode ser um dos seguintes valores: `unset`, `initial`, `inherit`, `will-change`, `auto`, `scroll-position`, ou `contents`. A especificação não define o comportamento de um valor em particular, mas é comum pro `transform` ser uma camada de composição. O [Chrome atualmente toma duas ações](https://github.com/operasoftware/devopera/pull/330), dadas as propriedades particulares do CSS: estabelece uma nova camada de composição ou um novo [stacking context](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Glossary/stacking_context).

#### Exemplo:

```
.slide:hover { 
    will-change: opacity;
}
```

No exemplo acima ao passar o mouse por cima do elemento com a classe **slide**, o navegador irá realizar otimizações, pois o **autor do código indicou que a seguir irá ocorrer uma mudança na propriedade opacity**.

---

## Que tipo de otimização o navegador consegue fazer quando a propriedade é utilizada?

As otimizações realizadas pelos navegadores através da propriedade `will-change` são todas focadas em performance. Elas podem aumentar a capacidade de resposta de uma página, fazendo o trabalho potencialmente caro, antes do tempo em que eles realmente serão necessários. Traduzindo, o navegador deixa "pré-carregado", o trabalho pesado que ele faria, no momento da alteração de uma propriedade CSS, esperando somente o momento de exibi-las. Assim é possível ganhar velocidade de processamento.

Vale aqui fazer uma ressalva. **Usar essa propriedade pode ser complicado!** O navegador já tenta ao máximo otimizar tudo, então você não deve aplicar `will-change` em muitos elementos. Quando utilizado em excesso pode retardar o carregamento da página em alguns casos ou consumir uma grande quantidade de recursos. Vamos a um exemplo de utilização ruim do `will-change`:

```
.separador {
  will-change: transform;
}
```

Nesse caso qualquer elemento em que a classe **separador** for aplicada, imediatamente o navegador irá entender que a propriedade indicada no `will-change` irá ser alterada em breve, o que irá fazer com que o navegador mantenha a otimização em memória por muito mais tempo que o necessário. Por manter na memória entendemos que, o navegador prepara as otimizações e as armazenam em tempo de execução na memória, afim de esperar o momento certo de exibi-las.

---

## Quando o uso desta propriedade é necessário?

Tendo em vista que o objetivo da propriedade `will-change` é ganho de performance, o uso da mesma deve ser feito quando o tempo de resposta de uma página não estiver satisfatório, devido a problemas de renderização.

Fica a dica chave: **Se sua página está performando bem, não adicione a propriedade `will-change` nos elementos apenas para trazer mais velocidade. `will-change` é entendido como algo para ser usado como último recurso**, com o intuito de tentar solucionar problemas de performance. Ele não deve ser usado para antecipar esses possíveis problemas. O uso excessivo do `will-change` poderá resultar em excessivo uso de memória e causar uma renderização mais complexa enquanto o browser tenta se preparar para uma possível mudança. Isso levará a um pior desempenho.

---

## Conclusão

Para que fique bem claro, utilize `will-change` somente se você já está com um problema de performance nas mãos, caso contrário você pode acabar arrumando um.

Comment: Você consegue dissertar melhor sobre o que acontece no navegador para que essa otimização seja possível? O que seria exatamente esse "manter na memória por mais tempo"?

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Como eu citei acima, essa otimização se torna possível a partir do momento em o navegador deixa "pré-carregado", o trabalho pesado que ele faria, no momento da alteração de um propriedade CSS, esperando somente o momento de exibi-las. Assim é possível ganhar velocidade de processamento. Sobre "manter na memória", fiz um adendo no texto para maior entendimento.

Comment: Em geral, essas otimizações não envolvem transferir o processamento para a GPU em vez da CPU?

Comment: @bfavaretto O processo de renderização envolve é claro GPU e CPU. Seguindo o raciocínio de que a propriedade `will-change` "pré-carrega" as alterações, mas não as exibe, o ganho principal seria na parte de CPU. Veja, não necessariamente estamos transferindo responsabilidade de processamento de um componente para outro, e sim ganhando tempo, já adiantando o processamento da CPU, deixando somente a GPU para o momento da exibição.